# Could I call notify() method in __construct() for SplSubject implemented class?

Tags: php, observer-pattern, observers

I have written a class which is implemented `SplSubject`. When I called notify() method from this class constructor it did not work.

```
// SplSubject
class A implement SqlSubject
{
   public function __construct()
   {
        $this->notify('Event', $data);
   }
}

// SqlObserver

class B implements SplObserver
{
    public function update(SplSubject $subject, $event = null, $data = null)
    {
        echo "Fired " . $event . ' event';
    }
}

// Usage

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->attach($b);
```

But notify did not work. If I call notify in another method instead of constructor it works fine.
My question is, is there any way to notify observer class from subject class constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `constructor` for `$a` runs before `$b` is attached. You could create a factory:

```
public static function createA() {
    $a = new A;
    $b = new B;
    $a->attach($b);
    $a->notify('Event', $data);
    return $a;
}
```

Or, you could pass `$b` to the `constructor` and `attach` it before notifying:

```
   public function __construct($b)
   {
        $this->attach($b);
        $this->notify('Event', $data);
   }
```